# How to find the href attribute of the videos on twitch through selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to find the twitch video IDs of all videos for a specific user. So for example on this page
https://www.twitch.tv/dyrus/videos/all

So here we have all videos linked, but its not quite so simple as to just scrape the html and find the links since they are generated dynamically it seems.

So I heard about selenium and did something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Change path here obviously
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Jason/Downloads/chromedriver') 
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/dyrus/videos/all')
link_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")


for link in link_element:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))

driver.close()
```

This returns me a bunch of links on the page but not the videos, they lie "deeper" I think, any input?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused at what exactly you're looking for.  The links that come back point to the page for each video.  This is not what you're looking for?  You are looking for access directly to each video instead?

Comment: Hmm I get a bunch of link but non to videos, do you get links on the form
https://twitch.tv/dyrus/videos/XXXXX

Comment: the href values appear to be links to pages that show each video

Comment: Can you give an example of a link you get out from this? Because I don't get a single link to a video

Comment: JeffC's answer below should give you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still suggest a couple of changes as follows:

- Always open the *Web Browser* in **maximized** mode so that all/majority of the desired elements are within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- If you are on *Windows OS* you need to append the extension `.exe` at the end of the *WebDriver* variant name, e.g. **chromedriver.exe**
- While you identify for elements always try to include the `class` attribute in your *Locator Strategy*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` at the end of your `@Test` to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Here is your own code block with the above mentioned tweaks:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/dyrus/videos/all')
  link_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.tw-interactive.tw-link[data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")))
  for link in link_elements:
      print(link.get_attribute('href'))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/295314690
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/294901947
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/294472813
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/294075254
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/293617036
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/293236560
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/292800601
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/292409437
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/292328170
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/292032996
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/291625563
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/291192151
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/290824842
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/290434348
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/290021370
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/289561690
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/289495488
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/289138003
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/289110429
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/288804893
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/288784992
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/288687479
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/288432438
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/288117849
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/288004968
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/287689102
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/287451192
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/287267032
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/287017431
  https://www.twitch.tv/videos/286819343
  ```

Answer (score 0):

With your locator, you are returning every element on the page that contains an `href` attribute. You can be a little more specific than that and get what you are looking for. Switch to a CSS selector...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

# Change path here obviously
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Jason/Downloads/chromedriver') 
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/dyrus/videos/all')
links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")))

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))

driver.close()
```

That prints 40 links from the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get 0 prints from this code. links = [] after this is run for some reason

Comment: Sorry, I ran this several times and it always worked but I think I just got lucky. I think it was a timing issue so I added a wait and it's working now.

Comment: There is a parenthesis error in the code which you might want to fix if someone else come in here looking but other than that it worked wonders, thank you! :)

Comment: If you know where the parenthesis mistake is, please fix it or tell me where it is so I can.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: On the links line there should be a another closing parenthesis at the end and not one closing around By.CSS_SELECTOR

Comment: Thanks... fixed. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted so the question doesn't get left unanswered.